# Referencing one strategy through another

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

When defining strategies, is it possible to reference another strategy?

```py
@given(maximum=strategies.floats(min_value=0),
       actual=strategies.floats(max_value=maximum))
def foo(maximum, actual):
    pass
```

This throws `NameError: 'maximum' not defined'`

Edit:

A workaround (or perhaps *the* workaround), is to use hypothesis's `assume` function. In my case, it looks like:

```py
@given(maximum=strategies.floats(min_value=0),
       actual=strategies.floats(min_value=0))
def foo(maximum, actual):
    assume(actual <= maximum)
    pass
```

Comment: What does given do?

Comment: It's from the hypothesis library for unit testing. It generates a myriad of values. You use it so that you don't have to just choose a couple of arbitrary values for your unit test and hope that it won't break for other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options can be summarised as "do it by rejecting some examples" (with `.filter()` or `assume()`, or "do it by construction".

The latter is generally more efficient, though it may require more code.  If you *do* want to try satisfying your constraints by construction, you'll need to either write a `@st.composite` strategy that supplies several arguments as a tuple; or go all the way to the `st.data()` strategy and draw interactively inside your test.

Or... in simple cases like this one, you could just put `if actual > maximum: actual, maximum = maximum, actual` at the top of the test function.